# Laravel: Unable To Add Record Many to many Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I want to add record using many to many relationship with **Laravel 6**. 
I have a User which may have many roles like admin, blogger etc

Here is my function in User Model

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id', 'id'
    );
}
```

Here is the Request data after form submission

```
array:5 [▼
    "_token" => "asdnkasdjisajdmasnduajid"
    "email" => "admin@admin.com"
    "roles" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "3"
    ]
]
```

I have Tried this method to save my records

```
$users = [
    'name'     => $request->name,
    'email'    => $request->email,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    'status'   => 'active',
];
$user = User::create($users);

if ($user) {
    $role = $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
    if (!$role) {
        Session::flash('error', "Unable to create Role at this moment");

        return redirect()->back();
    }
    Session::flash('status', 'User Created Successfully');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I am getting

> Unable to create Role at this moment

Comment: Your `if (!$role)` will always evaluate to `true` because `attach()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Silly me! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attach()` method of a many to many relationship [doesn't return anything](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_attach). 
Your role variable will therefore always be empty, even when a role is successfully attached to a user.

Try this instead:

```
$users = [
    'name'     => $request->name,
    'email'    => $request->email,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    'status'   => 'active',
];

$user = User::create($users);

if (!$user instanceof User) {
    Session::flash('error', "Unable to create User at this moment");
    return redirect()->back();
}

$user->roles()->attach($request->roles);

if (!$user->roles) {
    Session::flash('error', "Unable to create Role at this moment");
    return redirect()->back();
}

Session::flash('status', 'User Created Successfully');
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Silly me I forgot

Comment: @HamzaAfzal Did this answer your question?